# Key combination for each language

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, layout

I want to have a combination for several language layout.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> - English US
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> - Romanian STANDARD
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> - German
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> - Swedish

However, I can't find the Romanian STANDARD one. I have done all the Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Costum Shortcuts thing, and using `setxkbmap -layout ro` does not do it for me.

How can I choose the Romanian STANDARD keyboard? I don't want to press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> a every time I want to write ă and so on. I am a new Ubuntu user, so I am sorry for asking such basic questions.

Comment: From the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_keyboard_layout), The “secondary” layout is mainly used by programmers and it does not contradict the physical arrangement of keys on a US-style keyboard. The “secondary” arrangement is used as the default one by the majority of GNU/Linux distributions.

Comment: I know it is used by programmers, but is there anything I can do to use the Standard version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, solved it.
I had to type in `setxkbmap -layout ro std` in order for it to use the STANDARD Romanian keyboard. One issue is that on some websites swapping between layouts like that focuses out of the page and I have to click on the page again, but I'll just have to figure that one out.